# How to interpret the second part of an auto arima result in R?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am performing a `time series` analysis on my data and I have run the auto arima function to determine the best coefficients to use in my `ARIMA` model.

```
model1 <- auto.arima(log(mydata_ts))
model1

Series: log(mydata_ts) 
ARIMA(2,1,1)(1,0,0)[12] 

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2     ma1    sar1
      -1.1413  -0.3872  0.9453  0.7572
s.e.   0.1432   0.1362  0.0593  0.0830

sigma^2 estimated as 0.006575:  log likelihood=48.35
AIC=-86.69   AICc=-85.23   BIC=-77.44
```

I understand that (2,1,1) in the result above refer to the values of p, d and q that will be used in the `ARIMA` model. 
But what about (1,0,0)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617662/extract-arima-specificaiton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ARIMA(2,1,1)(1,0,0)[12]` is seasonal ARIMA. `[12]` stands for number of periods in season, i.e. months in year in this case. `(1,0,0)` stands for seasonal part of model. Take a look at [this](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/67).

Comment: Thanks. If I understand well, this is how I plug in those figures:
fit <- arima(log(mydata_ts), c(2, 1, 1),seasonal = list(order = c(1, 0, 0), period = 12))

Comment: exactly what i wanted!

Comment: The link doesnt work anymore.